A doubt in an argument in the Theorem 3.4, chapter 4, Complex analysis by E. Stein and R. Shakarchi
I want to prove that $\hat{f_{\epsilon}}$ converges to $\hat{f}$. By the autor's argument, i understood that is necessary to aply the dominated convergence theorem for improper riemann integrals, but i wasn't able to do it. We have this:
$$|\hat{f_{\epsilon}}(\xi) - \hat{f}(\xi)| \le \int_{-\infty}^{-\infty} \frac{A}{1+x^2}\Big[\frac{1}{(1+i\epsilon x)^2} -1\Big]dx,$$ because $|f(x)| \le \frac{A}{1 + x^2}$ and $f_{\epsilon}(x) = \frac{f(z)}{(1+i\epsilon z)^2}$. So my goal was to find a Riemann integrable function $g$ such that $\frac{A}{1+x^2}\Big[\frac{1}{(1+i\epsilon x)^2} -1\Big] \le g(x)$ and to aply the theorem observing that we have pointwise convergence to $0$. However, i didn't find it.
Is this the correct idea? If the answer is "yes", can anyone help me to find a function g?

I will assume that $\epsilon$ is real. Then
$$\left|\frac1{(1+ix\epsilon)^2}-1\right|\leq\frac1{|1+ix\epsilon|^2}+1\leq1+1\leq2.$$ We can thus take $$g(x)=\frac{2A}{x^2+1}.$$

Thank you so much!
